# Limiting the number times while loop loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
    <div class="teachers1">
      <div class="teamySlides">
        <div class="yourteachers">
          <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<a class="teachers" href="teacherinfo.php?id=' . $row['IDNum'] . '">
                      <img src="pictures/blank photo.png" class="teacherpic"><br>
                      <span>'.$row['LastName'].'</span><br>
                      <span>'.$row['Grade'].' - </span>
                      <span>'.$row['Section'].'</span>
                    </a>';
            }
          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="tplusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="tplusSlides(1)">❯</a>
      <div class="dot-container">
        <span class="tdot" onclick="tcurrentSlide(1)"></span> 
        <span class="tdot" onclick="tcurrentSlide(2)"></span> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

The code above is used to generate objects based on how many the data is on the database. To better understand it here is a picture of the system:

[image]

The problem is when the data exceed 8, the objects do not go to the next page. The reason is that I dont know how to do that.

For example I clicked the right arrow ">" the code must go to the second page and so on with the rest of the object.

Can anyone help me or can anyone provide me with the syntax? Thanks.

Javascript:

```
var ti;
    var tslides = document.getElementsByClassName("yourteachers");
    var tdots = document.getElementsByClassName("tdot");
    if (n > tslides.length) 
      tslideIndex = 1
    if (n < 1) 
      tslideIndex = tslides.length
    for (ti = 0; ti < tslides.length; ti++) 
        tslides[ti].style.display = "none";  
    for (ti = 0; ti < tdots.length; ti++) 
      tdots[ti].className = tdots[ti].className.replace(" active", "");
    tslides[tslideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    tdots[tslideIndex-1].className += " active";
```

Comment: Post your JS to so we can see what your functions are doing

Comment: That is my javascript for going to the next or previous page.

Comment: You have to generate multiple `<div class="teamySlides">...</divs>` divisions in PHP to hold up to 8 photos, and then generate up to 8 images within each `teamySlide` division. That requires two nested loops in page generation and the posted PHP only shows one. See if you can add the outer loop  knowing what it has to do. (The posted JS code works perfectly on the  browser side and is not part of the problem.)

Comment: I already added the second div but there is no population inside of it. Another problem that I have, is if I add another picture and it exceed 8 picture again, I want it to be automatic. Meaning it will generate its own "teamySlides".

Comment: If you have `n` slides, the outer loop has to loop `Math.ceil( n / 8)` times. The inner loop has to loop up to the minimum of 8 or the number of images remaining. This is how to translate "automatic" into PHP - it' not a keyword :-)

Comment: @traktor53 can you show me in codes?

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: You have to use LIMIT and Offset in your MySQL Query and pass the pageParameter to the page.

https://www.guru99.com/limit.html